# What are important mongo data files for backup

Tags: mongodb, backup, database-backups

If I want to backup database by copying raw files. What files do I need to copy ? only db-name.ns, db-name.0, db-name.1.... or whole folder (local.ns.., journal). I'm running replica set. I understand procedure for locking hidden secondary node and then copying files to new location. But I'm wondering do I need to copy whole folder or just some files.

Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: All of them. As obvious as it might sound. And here is why:

1. If you don't copy a namespaces file, your database will most likely not work.
2. When not copying all datafiles, some of your data is missing and your indices will point to void locations. The database in question *might* work (minus the data stored in the missing data file), but I would not bet on that – and since the data was important enough to create a backup in the first place, you don't want this to happen, do you?
3. Config, admin and local databases are vitally necessary for their respective features – and since you used the feature, you probably want to use it after a restore, too.

### How do I backup all files?

The best solution save for MMS backup I have found so far is to create LVM snapshots of the filesystem the MongoDB data resides on. In order for tis to work, the journal needs to be included. Usually, you don't need a dedicated backup node for this approach. It is *a bit* complicated to set up, though.

#### Preparing LVM backups

Let's assume you have your data in the default data directory `/data/db` and you have not changed any paths. Then you would mount a logical volume to `/data/db` and use this to hold the data. Assuming that you don't have anything like this, here is a step by step guide:

1. Create a logical volume big enough to hold your data. I will call that one `/dev/VolGroup/LogVol1` from now on. **Make sure that you only use about 80% of the available disk space in the volume group for creating the logical volume.**
2. Create a filesystem on the logical volume. I prefer XFS, so we create an xfs filesystem on `/dev/VolGroup/LogVol1`:

   ```
   mkfs.xfs /dev/VolGroup/LogVol1
   ```
3. Mount the newly created filesystem on `/mnt`

   ```
   mount /dev/VolGroup/LogVol1 /mnt
   ```
4. Shut down `mongod`:

   ```
   killall mongod
   ```

   (Note that the upstart scripts sometimes have problems shutting down mongod, and this command gracefully stops mongod anyway).
5. Copy the datafiles from `/data/db`to `/mnt`by issuing

   ```
   cp -a /data/db/* /mnt
   ```
6. Adjust your `/etc/fstab` so that the logical volume gets mounted on reboot:

   ```
   # The noatime parameter increases io speed of mongod significantly
   /dev/VolGroup/LogVol1   /data/db   xfs   defaults,noatime    0    1
   ```
7. Umount the logical volume from it's current outpoint and remount it on the correct one:

   ```
   cd && umount /mnt/ && mount /data/db
   ```
8. Restart mongod

#### Creating a backup

Creating a backup now becomes as easy as

1. Create a snapshot:

   ```
   lvcreate -l100%FREE -s -n mongo_backup /dev/VolGroup/LogVol1
   ```
2. Mount the snapshot:

   ```
   mount /dev/VolGroup/mongo_backup /mnt
   ```
3. Copy it somewhere. The reason we need to do this is that the snapshot can only be held up until the changes to the data files do not exceed the space in the volume group you did not allocate during preparation. For example, if you have a 100GB disk and you allocated 80GB for `/dev/VolGroup/LogVol1`, the snapshot size would be 20GB. While the changes on the filesystem from the point you took the snapshot are less than 20GB, everything runs fine. After that, the filesystem  will refuse to take any changes. So you aren't in a hurry, but you should definitely move the data to an offsite location, an FTP server or whatever you deem appropriate. Note that compressing the datafiles can take quite long and you might run out of "change space" before finishing that. Personally, I like to have a slower HDD as a temporary place to store the backup, doing all other operations on the HDD. So my copy command looks like

   ```
   cp -a /mnt/* /home/mongobackup/backups
   ```

when the HDD is mounted on /home/mongobackup.

4. Destroy the snapshot:

   ```
   umount /mnt && lvremove /dev/VolGroup/mongo_backup
   ```

   The space allocated for the snapshot is released and the restrictions to the amount of changes to the filesystem are removed.

Comment: Thank you all on answers. now I'm wondering what is the purpose of mongodump, it only saves user's database data. without journal/localdb. Can somebody explain in which scenario would I use mongodump/restore and in which copying raw db folder. I would like to know the differences. Once again thank you all on your replies.

Comment: In short: copying the folder is pretty much what I have described, although a bit elaborated. I personally use mongodump for data migrations from standalone instances to sharded (possibly pre-split) environments or when I only want to backup specific databases or collections, for use as test data after anonymization.

Answer (score 0):

Whole db-Data folder + where ever you have your logs and journalling

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to backup data on MongoDB would be to use Mongo monitoring Service(MMS). All other solutions including copying files manually, mongodump, mongoexport are way behind MMS.